# Unable to connect to storage account from Azure functions. Need to store the file in storage account through Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Requirement is to store the file in storage account through Azure Functions in PowerShell.
Below is the code

```
$todaydate = Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yy 
$LogFull = "AzureScan-$todaydate.log" 
$LogItem = New-Item -ItemType File -Name $LogFull

"  Text to write" | Out-File -FilePath $LogFull -Append

#Get key to storage account
$acctKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name amsaccount1 - 
ResourceGroupName RGAMS).Value[0]

#Map to the reports BLOB context
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 
"amsaccount1" -StorageAccountKey $acctKey

#Copy the file to the storage account
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $LogFull -Container "files" -BlobType 
"Block" -Context $storageContext -Verbose
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error you're getting. Also, please format your code so that it becomes readable.

Comment: Edited. it is not throwing an error but doesn't store the file in storage account.